# Streaming output from Invoke-WebRequest to screen

Tags: powershell, curl

I am trying to invoke a web request which will print out a stream of plain-text live. It currently works, but doesn't produce any output until the request is complete. I'm trying to find a way to see the content as soon as comes down the wire. I can currently do with with a curl command from a Linux box and it shows be each line of output as soon as it's produced. The PowerShell command I'm trying to use it something like this:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Body @{id=123} -Method POST -Uri http://server/run_command/
```

The corresponding curl command on Linux is:

```
curl -d id=123 -X POST http://server/run_command/ --no-buffer
```

The `--no-buffer` option is only needed when sending the output to another command like grep. How can I accomplish this using just PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to test this myself right now, but have you tried expanding the content?

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Body @{id=123} -Method POST -Uri http://server/run_command/).Content
```

Comment: Just tested this, it does not work. PowerShell displays a progress pop-up overlay indicating that it is reading the web response. No content is displayed until the response is complete, and if the response produces an infinite amount of data, no content is ever displayed.

Comment: If you have a publicly addressable URL in mind, share it with us. I may be able to do some more robust testing.if I was familiar with the source data you are wanting to stream.

Comment: I'll see if I can't stand something up for a while for you to try with :-)

Comment: As of right now, I have a server up that streams a result. Try the following command: `curl.exe --no-buffer http://laliari.logiclrd.cx:5000/v1/sing` It'll sing as long as you let it, 200ms between lines, ^C to stop. Can you reproduce this client behaviour with PowerShell?

Comment: I push the .RawContent to an HTML file. From there you can open the file in a browser and see exactly what it is you're looking at (in case the HTML isn't too clear)

Answer (score 0):

There are other APIs that allow reading response stream without buffering it in full.

For example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=net-5.0

PowerShell version of the same could look like this:

```
$webrequest = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Archive")
$responseStream = $webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
$streamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($responseStream)

[char[]]$buffer = [char[]]::new(256)
while (($count = $streamReader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0)
{    
    # output count characters of the buffer
}

$response.Close() > $null
$responseStream.Close() > $null
```